# Cannot SSH into EC2 instance after creating second user and public key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, server, recovery

I might have done something extremely stupid. I don't really know what I'm doing with this but have been following online guides to set up an EC2 Instance running Bitnami Wordpress.

Today I attempted to follow this guide to link Vaultpress to my instance:
https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/2016/04/connect-vaultpress-aws-ec2-instance/

I think I may have misstepped and pasted the public key text in the .ssh/authorized_keys inside the root user, overwriting whatever was there, (if there is information there by default?). I think, however, I was under a new user I created earlier, named vaultpress.

It is also possible that when I tried to add security groups I overwrote something something important. I have now reset the default VPC group and Security group generated by AWS Marketplace to 0.0.0.0/0 for SSH, so if I understand correctly that should be OK now?

Either way, I can now no longer SSH in with my .pem file. I did CHMOD 600 to the .pem file and used the standard ssh -i "thefile.pem" bitnami@address.com. Not sure where to go from here. Are there other ways to access the instance?

I get permission denied (public key)

ANY HELP REALLY APPRECIATED!
I thought I was going to make big track on my project with my day off today. Guess it's one step forward and two back today.

Comment: Did you take a snapshot before doing such changes? If yes, just restore it. If not, try connecting as root using the private key of your other user. If it doesn't work and you don't know what to do next, attach the root volume to another instance, mount it to `/mnt/something`, then edit `/mnt/something/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and change it back to whatever is correct. Unmount, reattach the volume to the original instance, start it up, ssh, done.

Comment: I don't have a private key of the newly created vaultpress user. I just uploaded the public key that the plug in recommended. I don't see a private key anywhere, I think that's within the plug in. I don't understand the root volume in another instance, but I'll google around and see if I can figure out what you're suggesting here.Thank you.

Comment: It's pretty much like taking the HDD/SDD from one physical machine and plugging it into another. You can do the same with EBS volumes. The root volume is the one containing the root filesystem, which in the Linux world means it contains the files/directories below `/ ` (example, `/usr`, `/etc`, etc).

Comment: Okay. I'm going to wait to see if AWS support has any specific help for now but if all else fails I guess I'm going that direction. It probably isn't but seems really complicated to me. I'll work on finding out how to do that. Thank you for this.

Comment: SOLVED! If any future AWS guys run in to this, this tutorial was a lifesaver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OF2AOekW4IE